# Git goes too slow in Docker container

Tags: git, docker, containers

I execute the command `git status` inside a container of Docker and after more than 6 seconds I get this output.

```
It took 6.52 seconds to enumerate untracked files. 'status -uno'
may speed it up, but you have to be careful not to forget to add
new files yourself (see 'git help status').
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Any solution to make it go faster?

Comment: What host OS?  Docker Toolbox or a desktop app or native on Linux?

Comment: Show the Dockerfile, the docker run command or the docker compose

Comment: I use Desktop app in Windows 10 PRO

Comment: what is the performance of this git repo on the machine itself, without Docker? Maybe it is just too big

Comment: I installed the git in the container and then I executed git status. In Windows Desktop it goes very fast. The project is Magento 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem until I allocated more resources Docker by clicking on "Settings" then "Advanced". You'll want to make sure that you're using the latest version of Docker Desktop (for Windows).

By default, the Hyper-V virtual machine in which Docker runs only gets 2 CPUs and 2GB RAM.

Once I bumped up the VM to 3 CPUs and 5GB RAM, I had no problem doing "git status", "git checkout", etc. Before the change, these commands would often never complete.

Before making the change, I went into "Hyper-V Manager" and clicked on the "Memory" tab at the bottom. It showed that "Memory Demand" was about 3GB, so I'm guessing the VM was swapping to disk and that would've caused all kinds of problems. Now, I still have about 2GB of headroom with my RAM, and performance is much much better.

I hope this helps you!

Comment: In terms of size, there were around 7000 files, the .git directory was 3.5G, and .8GB of files in the working directory.

Comment: There is something wrong with git and mac apparently. It is not about the resources!

Comment: @MortezaSepehriNiya: How do you think that your comment is relevant?

First, we were talking about a Windows host.

Second, we were talking about Git running in a Hyper-V virtual machine running Linux. 

Third, I highly doubt that there is "something wrong with git and mac", as many people around the world use them together every day with no problems. 

In my case, my Hyper-V virtual machine's memory was over-committed which caused Git to perform slowly. I had the numbers to back that up. It was about resources at that time.

Not all issues will be resources but this one was for me.

Comment: I think if you doubt that there is "something wrong with git and mac" does not help because you need to install docker on mac and install git on a container and interact with git in the docker to see it is so slow and all the people you mentioned are using these have reported that. But about being revlevent you are right. My answer was not relevant to this question

Comment: 3gb memory and 6 cores with a relatively light load, and "git status" takes over 3 seconds. The rest of usage within the container is fine, i can run heavy processes quite easily, definitely seems to be an issue with running git in a container (am running an ubuntu container on mac)

Comment: @Brett: Take a look at your Hypervisor. I don't use Mac, but I can assure you I've overloaded the memory on the DockerDesktopVM on Windows. Right now I have 6 containers running and my Hyper-V VM has "Assigned Memory: 5120MB" and "Memory Demand: 4710MB". 

If my Hyper-V VM only had 3GB of memory, it would be struggling.

You may want to think about what you mean by "run heavy processes" as well. When I had a VM with 2GB, I didn't have any issues aside from Git. But Git was the only thing heavy on memory use.

Comment: Btw, I only have 2 CPUs devoted to my DockerDesktopVM on Windows. The host has 6 cores, 12 logical processors. 

I can't speak to Mac with 100% certainty, but the issue with Windows was alleviated by assigning enough memory to meet demand.